# How to disable a Google Chrome shortcut on mac?

Tags: google-chrome

I am using Google Chrome on Mac (previously used Safari, but I do need to use quite a lot of Google Sheets etc. and they don't work there that well). I am having a problem when I want to type the Polish letter "ą" (option+a) it activates a shortcut that switches between the open tabs. Is there any way of disabling this specific shortcut?

I have tried the "Disable keyboard shortcuts" and "Shortkeys" extension but I can't set it up because I can't type the shortcut - it toggles the tabs instead. In shortkeys I write "option+a" or "alt+a" and also nothing changes.

Comment: I can't repro. Opt/a does nothing [except type `å` if I'm in a text area]. Does it do the same if you switch your input language to English?

Comment: Yes, the same thing is happening!

Comment: I'm really not sure what's happening. Switch Tabs in Chrome should be Cmd/[number], same as Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restoring all settings to default somehow worked!